# How to make use of spring declarative transactions along with EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, entitymanagerfactory

I have defined the following configuration in my application

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="database1")
public DataSource rameshDS()
{
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "rameshEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean rameshEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
 return builder
               .dataSource(rameshDS())
               .packages("com.nandagiri.entities")
               .build();
   }

@Primary
@Bean(name = "rameshTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager rameshTransactionManager(
        final @Qualifier("rameshEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean rameshEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(rameshEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
}
```

If I try to insert data into one of the tables in the following way, the data is not persisted. But if I uncomment the lines to explicitly begin/commit transactions then it is working fine. But, I wanted to use declarative way of transactions. How to achieve that?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("rameshEntityManagerFactory")
EntityManagerFactory rameshEntity;


@Override
@Transactional(value = "rameshTransactionManager")
public void storeInfo(Ramesh ramesh) 
{
    EntityManager em = rameshEntity.createEntityManager();
    //em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(ramesh);
    //em.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

If I persist the entities with repository interface it is working absolutely fine without any issues. please find the code below.

```
@Repository
public interface RameshRepository extends JpaRepository<Ramesh,      String>
{
 }

@Transactional(transactionManager = "rameshTransactionManager",  propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveRameshs()
{
    saveRamesh1();
    saveRamesh2();

}

@Transactional
public void saveRamesh1()
{
    Ramesh ramesh = new Ramesh();
    ramesh.setId("8");
    ramesh.setFname("jagadeesh");
    ramesh.setLname("K");

    repository.save(ramesh);

}

@Transactional
public void saveRamesh2()
{
    Ramesh ramesh = new Ramesh();
    ramesh.setId("9");
    ramesh.setFname("jagadeesh123");
    ramesh.setLname("k123");

    repository.save(ramesh);
    //int x = 5/0;
}
```

Comment: Did you enable transaction management ? [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

Comment: Yes. I have enabled it with that annotation already.  In fact, I have a interface extended JpaRepository and any operations using with @transactional working absolutely fine.         Note: Updated the post with that info

Comment: Is `storeInfo()` an internal method call ? Please share the code where you are calling the method.